# HTML5 JQuery - How to hide service calls from 'view source'?

Tags: jquery, html, wcf, encryption, asp.net-web-api

I'm making a HTML5, JQuery, CSS3 application. Was wondering if there is a way to hide the service calls from displaying to the end user if he chooses to do a 'view source'?

Maybe, show as encrypted or like wise?

Answers will be appreciated!

Cheers,
Anshuman

---

I found this on the net:
http://www.jquery4u.com/security/hide-jquery-source-code/

Has anyone used the tools mentioned in the page? How secure do they make the page? Will it affect the performance?

Comment: Yes, the URL needs to be hidden from the end users. JS files is not an option coz we can download them as well!

Comment: you could make a function to encrypt the URL, and then use an ajax call to show the service to the end user based on the location.hash from the URL! Put the encrypted after the # and will win!

Comment: well... if it's encrypted, what stops the user from using the encrypted url to get at the content? Or even get at it from the resources tab? You could verify the source of the request on the server-side, but that doesn't stop the user from using the console on your site to bypass that verification. There isn't much, if anything, you can do to prevent the user from viewing your resources.

Comment: Well, you could give an unique key as well to provide that access and decrypt the URL, supposing that there's no authentication avaible. Maybe a service that give's keys and decrypt the url and then redirect to the write service! If you provide more info about the plataform would help a lot!

Comment: UI is HTML5, CSS3, JQuery.
Data is managed thru service calls WCF 4.0 and ASP.NET Web APIs

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to hide?  Anything that comes down to the client can be viewed and analyzed by the user if they know what they are doing.  You have more than view source to worry about.  The person could use the developer toolbar, fiddler, wireshark, etc..., to look at the data you are sending down.  If it is not encrypted it can easily be extracted.

Comment: @Anshuman Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I did. But by applying membership to web api modules. Using the [Authorize] attribute. But there was no way, I could do it at the View Source stage. Now atleast unauthorized users cannot paste the Web API url and check out the results.

Comment: Authorization is the right approach. You can't hide the user's HTTP requests from themselves.